# How to show 'login error' and 'lost password' on my template page?

Tags: login, front-end

I'm providing front-end login in a template, using the function wp_login_form. It handles the redirection after login and logout pretty neatly! But if the username / password mismatch, or are non existent, the user is redirected to the admin login page, with the shaky js error. Also same is the case when I'm trying to reset the password, it takes me to the me backend page where I have to enter my email for resetting the password. I want to show both these activities on my template. Is there a way I could do this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You have to create three filters for this.

### Admin stuff inside a class

```
class WPSE29338_Admin {
    public static function setup() {
        add_filter('login_url', array(__CLASS__, 'modifyLoginURL'), 10, 2);
        add_filter('lostpassword_url', array(__CLASS__, 'modifyLostPasswordURL'), 10, 2);
        add_filter('register', array(__CLASS__, 'modifyRegisterURL'));
    }

    public static function modifyLoginURL($loginUrl, $redirect = '') {
        $loginUrl = site_url('login'); // Link to login URL

        if(!empty($redirect)) {
            $loginUrl = add_query_arg('redirect_to', urlencode($redirect), $loginUrl);
        }

        return $loginUrl;
    }

    public static function modifyLostPasswordURL($lostpwUrl, $redirect = '') {
        $lostpwUrl = wp_login_url() . '#lostpassword'; // Link to lostpassword URL

        if(!empty($redirect)) {
            $lostpwUrl = add_query_arg('redirect_to', urlencode($redirect), $lostpwUrl);
        }

        return $lostpwUrl;
    }

    public static function modifyRegisterURL($registerUrl) {
        if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
            if (get_option('users_can_register')) {
                $registerUrl = '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . '#register" class="btn">' . __('Register') . '</a>'; // Link to register URL
            } else {
                $registerUrl = '';
            }
        }

        return $registerUrl;
    }
}
```

First we need to filter the output of the function `wp_login_url()` which is used by `wp_login_form()` in the forms `action` attribute.

Look at the method `modifyLoginUrl()`. Here we store the URL of the page `login` inside the variable `$loginUrl`. This page must exists inside WordPress, so create it first.

Next we need a filter for the function `wp_lostpassword_url()` and `wp_register()`. It's basically the same. The URL of the site is stored inside the variable `$lostpwUrl` and `$registerUrl`.

Last but not least, you have to call the class on the right action hook. For themes this should be `after_setup_theme` and for plugins you can use `plugins_loaded`.

### Themes / functions.php

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpse29338_admin_init');
function wpse29338_admin_init() {
    WPSE29338_Admin::setup();
}
```

### Plugins

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'wpse29338_admin_init');
function wpse29338_admin_init() {
    WPSE29338_Admin::setup();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bump this, but I would love to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out! In the code you provided, what should be changed by me?

Comment: Bram, if you're creating a custom theme, then put all of the first and second blocks of code in your theme functions file. If you're creating a plugin, then put the first and third blocks of code in your plugin file. It looks like the only thing you might have to modify is the 9th line of the class, where it says `$loginUrl = site_url('login'); // Link to login URL`. Just change 'login' to match the slug of the login page you'd like to use. 

Unless Rofflox made a syntax error that I'm not seeing, this looks like it'd work beautifully.

Comment: @guiniveretoo Thanks for your reply! The problem is that I work with a dropdown form that can be accessed from any page on the website. So, there is no definite slug possible, because people can login from any page ... So, what should I put there?

Comment: Bram - Wordpress needs a login url so that if there's some user error or similar, there's somewhere for them to go and reset their password or sign up for an account. Setting a login url provides that page. I did exactly this setup with a project last year: a javascript login box that appeared with the login form - if they enter their info correctly, it sends them to wp-admin; if not, they end up on the custom login page to either try again or reset their password.